# stop R script with exit status 0

Tags: r

There is a condition at which I need to stop R script from proceeding and it should exit gracefully. Scripts are going to run through cron so I don't want to use `quit` because I am not sure how that would affect my running scripts at that time.

Is there a way to `stop` script with exit status `0`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `quit()`:

```
$ Rscript -e "print('hello'); quit(status=0, save='no')"
[1] "hello"

$ echo $?
0
```

I chose `save='no'` since it's unlikely you want the environment/workspace saved to an R data file in that directory.

Comment: Would that also not interfere with my other R scripts running through cron at the same time?

Comment: How would that be possible? R isn't "running in the background" and processing all scripts. Each call is a new R interpreter session. You may want to read up on the basics of Linux processes and how cron actually works if you're going to be relying on it for real world production tasks.